# How do I reset the snapshots of an APFS external drive?

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility

In the past couple weeks, my time machine is complaining that it's not managed to complete a backup. It turns out it aren't able to create a snapshot in one of my external drives. Error message is below:

[image]

This error message is not very consistent, where sometimes it just gives a generic Time Machine error message. Upon some debugging I found that perhaps using Disk Utility to repair the disk is a solution. I ended up with another error.

[image]

My last resort was to try to just remove the snapshots manually. However, it seems like the command line tool does not allow me to specify the location of the snapshots I want to delete? i.e. This command: `sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2020-xx-xx` only takes snapshot names which are in dates. I'm not so sure if this is the correct way to delete the snapshots, but even after deleteing all of them that are listed in `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /dev/disk5`, I still could not back up to time machine.

Furthermore, I also ended up erasing my whole time machine and then trying to back up again from scratch to no avail. Would anyone be able to tell me what's happening to my drive and what's the solution? I feel like the only thing I could do now is just to erase the drive completely and start again.